# How to move map when sidebar is open?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework, gis

I am trying to develop an ionic application like screenshot which I put here.
But there is something that I want to know about google map, or whatever the answer is it.

as you see, I opened the sidebar.the thing that I want to do is moving the map during this situation.
is it posible ? thanks in advance..

this is my map.html page.

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button class="button button-icon icon ion-pinpoint" ng-click="goster()"></button>
</ion-nav-buttons>

<ion-content>
    <div class="mapWrap" data-tap-disabled="true">

        <ng-map  center="{{konum.lat}},{{konum.lon}}"
                on-click="hideInfo()"
                disable-default-u-i="true"
                zoom="15">
```

```
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

here is my menu.html page.

```
<ion-side-menus>
    <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="nav-title-slide-ios7">
            <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"></i></ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-pane>
    <ion-side-menu side="left">

        <ion-content >


        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

[image]

Comment: I added some of the html codes of the page.

Comment: Have you tried to do something to make what you want to do work ?

Comment: I researched some issue about this topic.But they didn t help me.also I am on the new both js and ionic..Btw I am asking you any idea.I don't want you to give me the code..